# VisualState Name and GroupName, WinRT WinPRT

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, visualstatemanager, winprt

I'm trying to set custom visual states of multiple items like Button, GridViewItem, and ListBoxItem. It seems like I'm missing some states. I searched through the stackoverflow and msdn and could not find a list of possible visual states so that I can verify if I'm covering them all or not. 
Does anyone know somewhere I can find a list of VisualState Names and GroupNames?

Update: you can check the Templates for Button in Visual Studio but not for those items that cannot be added through the toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One place to find them is in control templates themselves. Right click a control in the designer view and extract the template to see what visual states it responds to.

Comment: You can do so for Button but not for items like GridViewItem.

Comment: You can. Right click a GridView, select Edit Additional Templates, then Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)/Edit a Copy. It is a pretty convoluted path, but it is there.

Comment: This helped, but it looks like there are some visualstates not covered in the generated template but effective.
e.g. GridViewItem template does not include SelectedPointerOver but assigning that visual state changes item behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why.